# Performance of appending to a list?

Tags: cassandra

This is my Cassandra model:   (id,date) -> field, field, field, List[User]

I want to append a new user to the end of the list for today.

Now, I want to understand this operation:

Is Cassandra able to just append the User to the end of the list or maybe I have to load the row, add the user to the list and the re-persist?

This is very crucial, performance-wise.

Comment: If your data model looks like this, then you shouldn't use a list and create a clustering column. You should post your actual schema (from cqlsh : describe schema ).

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented this is most probably not an optimal design choice that you have there, but you don't seem to be willing to share the actual schema.

Nevertheless here is a way to update a `set` in one go :

```
UPDATE users SET emails = emails + {'fb@friends.org'} WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

This comes directly from the [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_set_t.html).